# Keep the End Position of Animation

Tags: objective-c, animation

I tried everything, but everytime its the same problem:

i want to move a button for y = 276. when the animation ends, my buttons jumps back to the startposition, but i want that the endanimationposition is the new position, and the button has to stay there, until a new animation is called.

tried with

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        CGPoint p = _cell00.center;
        p.x += 100;
        _cell00.center = p;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
```

same issue like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
_cell00.frame = CGRectOffset(_cell00.frame, 0, 20);
}];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            _cell00.center = CGPointMake(0, 20.0);
        }];
```

EDIT:

I call this Animation with my Button called statisticsBUttonPressed.

```
- (IBAction)statisticsButtonPressed:(id)sender {


if (statOrGame == 0) {
    statOrGame = 1;
}else {
    statOrGame = 0;
}

NSLog(@"statOrGame? %d", statOrGame);
[self animateView:(UIButton *)sender];
}

-(void) animateView:(UIButton *)sender {

sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch
    NSLog(@"IS IPHONE 5");

    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
{
    if (statOrGame) {


        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
_cell00.frame = CGRectOffset(_cell00.frame, 0, 20);
}];

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you call this code? Can you post a bigger chunk?

Comment: ive edited my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using auto layout. You can't (just) change the *frame* of a view that is positioned by auto layout, because what positions the view is its constraints. You need to change the *constraints*. You can do this at the end of the animation, or you can simply animate the change of constraints.

Comment: you´re the best! i dont need auto layout, because i have for each device an own storyboard, i just unchecked autolayout and it works! many thanks!